# Как экспортировать трек из моих карт?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Есть моя карта, доступная по ссылке https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=mymaps%3AiDdaA5aqFpXZgt6fvhsySe8YlvbQfmsx&source=constructorLink я хочу экспортировать трек в KML или GPX.

Здесь https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/markers_3.html говорится про кнопку "Экспорт", но я не вижу её в интерфейсе карт.

Подскажите, как можно экспортировать трек (координаты + время)?

Answer (score 0):

Возможность экспорта данных в ряд форматов существует только в интерфейсе [Конструктора карт](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) и только для автора этой карты.

Координаты точек в этом случае будут выгружены, поскольку из них состоит линия. Однако временные метки самого трека на карте уже отсутствуют. Есть только две метки со стартом и финишем.

Если оригинальный трек не ваш и карту создавали не вы, попробуйте обратиться к её автору, если он вам известен. Яндекс таких данных разглашать не будет.